# Custom optimizer in PyTorch or TensorFlow 2.12.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to implement my custom optimizer in PyTorch or TensorFlow 2.12.0.
With help of ChatGPT I always get code that have errors, what's more I can't find any useful examples.

I would like to implement custom optimizer as:

d1 contains sign of current derivatives
d2 contains sign of previous derivatives
step_size is 1.0
step_size is divided by 2.0 if sign of d1 != d2
In PyTorch

I know that code has to look something like this:

```
import torch.optim as optim

class MyOpt(optim.Optimizer):
   def __init__(self, params, lr=1.0):
      defaults = dict(lr=lr, d1=None, d2=None)
      super(MyOpt, slef).__init__(params, defaults)

   def step(self):
      ???
```

Can anyone help me to code it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it.

```
class MyOptimizer(optim.Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, params, lr=1.0):
        defaults = dict(lr=lr)
        super(MyOptimizer, self).__init__(params, defaults)
        self.lr = {}
        self.d2 = {}

        for group in self.param_groups:
            for param in group['params']:
                self.lr[param] = torch.ones_like(param.data) * lr
                self.d2[param] = torch.ones_like(param.data)

    def step(self, closure=None):
        loss = None
        if closure is not None:
            loss = closure()

        for group in self.param_groups:
            for param in group['params']:
                if param.grad is None:
                    continue

                d1 = torch.sign(param.grad.data)
                t = torch.where(torch.sign(self.d2[param]) == d1, 1.0, 2.0)

                lr = self.lr[param]
                lr = lr / t

                self.lr[param] = lr
                param.data -= d1 * lr

                self.d2[param] = d1

        return loss
```

Answer (score 2):

The pytorch optimizers are complicated because they are general and optimized for performance. Implementing your own is relatively straightforward if you don't need it to be particularly robust. For example, a very simple implementation of gradient descent with momentum might look something like this.

```
from torch.optim import Optimizer

class SimpleGD(Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, params, lr, momentum=0.0):
        defaults = dict(lr=lr, momentum=momentum)
        super().__init__(params, defaults)

    @torch.no_grad()
    def step(self, closure=None):
        loss = None
        if closure is not None:
            loss = closure()
        for group in self.param_groups:
            for param in group['params']:
                grad = param.grad + group['momentum'] * self.state[param].get('momentum_buffer', 0)
                self.state[param]['momentum_buffer'] = grad
                param -= group['lr'] * grad
        return loss
```

Which should match the results of PyTorch's `SGD` with the same `lr` and `momentum` (and everything else defaulted).

For your case, you would need to compute sign of the gradients and cache them at each step similar to the way the `momentum_buffer` is cached in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely above ChatGPT's paygrade, whose bugs can be quite obscure by the way. If you cannot code it yourself, it is better to ask for someone else to code it for you. With regard to the question:

The step method self-explanatorily implements a step of the optimizer. In the step, you must write your optimizer core function. You can take the parameters that are stored in the object under the method self.param_groups if you copied code from e.g. pytorch SGD. Then you can perform your operations with d_p_list which is a group of self.param_groups.

Before your core function you should also initialize the loss by calling the closure, and at the end of the step function return the loss.

For more information, you can take a look at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD

Good luck.